# How to show Android MediaCodec decoded frames on GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mediacodec, glsurfaceview

I want to decoded H264 MediaCodec Frames to be shown on a GLSurfaceView. I use [EncodeDecode.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/EncodeDecodeTest.java) in Google Sources but I do not know how to draw the output on GLSurfaceView.

```
public void drawFrame(SurfaceTexture st) {
    checkGlError("onDrawFrame start");
    st.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
    checkGlError("glUseProgram");
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);
    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");
    mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
        TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
    checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
    checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
    GLES20.glFinish();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to render to a `GLSurfaceView` you need to define a `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` and implement the following methods: `onSurfaceCreated`, `onSurfaceChanged` , `onDrawFrame`.

See an example with explanations [here](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment)

Comment: THANK YOU! @dev.bmax